# Using placeholders in Informix SQL queries

Tags: sql, database, syntax, informix

How I can use the placeholders within dynamic SQL string in case when I need to assign one of input parameters twice? Following code doesn't work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION somefunc( p_name VARCHAR( 32 ), p_id INT, p_weight INT ) RETURNING INT;

    LET sp_id = 0;
    LET somearea=12;


    LET c_query ='SELECT FIRST 1 pr_id FROM sometable n WHERE n.pr_id> ? and n.pr_weight = ? ( UPPER( n.sname ) LIKE %UPPER(?))'||
    ' OR( UPPER(?) LIKE %UPPER( n.name)) ORDER BY 1, 2;';

    PREPARE c_stmt
    FROM c_query;

    DECLARE c_cur CURSOR FOR c_stmt;

    OPEN c_cur USING p_id, p_weight, p_name, p_name ;

    FETCH c_cur INTO sp_id;

    CLOSE c_cur;

    FREE c_cur;

    FREE c_stmt;

    RETURN sp_id;

END FUNCTION;
```

Comment: Ignoring the dynamic SQL, the string contains a bunch of gibberish, starting after the first `?` in `? ( UPPER( n.sname ) LIKE %UPPER(?))'`.  If you replaced that question mark with a value (say `13`), the rest of the code makes no sense; you can't have an open parenthesis there.  You cannot provide structural elements of a dynamic SQL statement as placeholders.  You can't provide table name or column names or function names; you can only provide values to be used in the SQL.  If you need table, column or function names, you have to 'edit' them into the SQL string that you prepare, etc.

Comment: I`m really sorry about that, but i actually do not understood your text. Could you please provide some little example that shows how the placeholders work and how they map to parameters and variables

Comment: Not tonight; it's an hour past bedtime.  If no-one else has done anything in the morning, I'll try.  I note that my answer to your other question has some dynamic SQL with placeholders in it.

Comment: Firstly i need to know what exactly you mean under dynamic sql)). I thought that my example also contains dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Umm... not quite sure to fully understand the question (or the purpose of that SQL, hope it's us a test as it does in deed look weird)

Anyway, this is your SPL with the correct syntax:

```
D:\infx\ids12>cat 1.sql
DROP TABLE sometable;
CREATE TABLE sometable  (name varchar(32), sname varchar(32), pr_id int, pr_weight int);

INSERT INTO sometable VALUES ('test','test',1,100);
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES ('tESt','tESt',2,200);
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES ('another','another',3,300);

DROP FUNCTION somefunc;
CREATE FUNCTION somefunc( p_name VARCHAR( 32 ), p_id INT, p_weight INT ) RETURNING INT;
    DEFINE sp_id int;
        DEFINE c_query varchar(200);

    LET sp_id = 0;
        LET c_query ="SELECT FIRST 1 pr_id FROM sometable n WHERE n.pr_id> ? and n.pr_weight = ? and ( UPPER( n.sname ) LIKE UPPER('%'||?||'%')) OR( UPPER('%'||?||'%') LIKE UPPER( n.name)) ORDER BY 1";

    PREPARE c_stmt
    FROM c_query;
    DECLARE c_cur CURSOR FOR c_stmt;
    OPEN c_cur USING p_id, p_weight, p_name, p_name ;
    FETCH c_cur INTO sp_id;
    CLOSE c_cur;

    FREE c_cur;
    FREE c_stmt;
    RETURN sp_id;

END FUNCTION;

--SELECT FIRST 1 * FROM sometable n WHERE n.pr_id> 1 and n.pr_weight = 200 and ( UPPER( n.sname ) LIKE UPPER('%'||'TEST'||'%')) OR ( UPPER('%'||'TEST'||'%') LIKE UPPER( n.name)) ORDER BY 1;

EXECUTE FUNCTION somefunc('TEST',1,200);

D:\infx\ids12>dbaccess stores7 1.sql
Database selected.
Table dropped.
Table created.
1 row(s) inserted.
1 row(s) inserted.
1 row(s) inserted.
Routine dropped.
Routine created.
(expression)
           2
1 row(s) retrieved.
Database closed.
D:\infx\ids12>
```

I think that what Jonathan was referring to when talking about dynamic SQL  is that you don't need to build or prepare a SELECT statement using place holders (?) inside a SPL. You can execute mostly 'any' SQL statement.
The SPL above could be rewrite like:

```
D:\infx\ids12>cat 2.sql
DROP FUNCTION somefunc_simple;

CREATE FUNCTION somefunc_simple( p_name VARCHAR( 32 ), p_id INT, p_weight INT )
RETURNING INT;
        DEFINE sp_id int;

        LET sp_id=(SELECT FIRST 1 pr_id  FROM sometable n WHERE n.pr_id> p_id and n.pr_weight = p_weight and ( UPPER( n.sname ) LIKE UPPER('%'||p_name||'%')) OR ( UPPER('%'||p_name||'%') LIKE UPPER( n.name)));

        RETURN sp_id;
END FUNCTION;

EXECUTE FUNCTION somefunc_simple('TEST',1,200);

D:\infx\ids12>dbaccess stores7 2.sql
Database selected.
Routine dropped.
Routine created.
(expression)

           2
1 row(s) retrieved.
Database closed.
D:\infx\ids12>
```

Have a read at the Informix SQL guide at

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls.htm

It should give you an idea of how to write Informix SQL and SPL and what functionality is supported.

Also, Dynamic SQL is explained here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/ids_esqlc_0528.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in your last example you didn`t use the order by statement

Comment: Still don't quite understand what you wanted to achieve with the SPL, but you can't use ORDER BY in a singleton SQL like the one above.

Comment: I need to get the result of the select query within foreach body, but as foreach does not support select statement in it body i wrapped the select query into the function. How it will be correct if i need to save query result into variable?

Comment: I'm even more confuse now ;)   Do you mean this FOREACH?  (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_458.htm)  because there is no FOREACH in the original SPL.

Comment: Yes, exactly it is. All questions in the informix db context; But i`ve already  successfully finished my task. Thanks for your help.